# Filter an XML column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

I have an xml type column `productsXML` in `product` table

```
Create Table Product
(
    ProductId Int,
    productsXML XML
)
```

```
Insert Into Product 
Values (1, '<products><productInfo><Item>Car</Item></productInfo></products>'),
       (2, '<products><productInfo><Item>Train</Item></productInfo></products>'),
       (3, '<products></products>')
```

```
ProductId productsXML
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1         <products><productInfo><Item>Car</Item></productInfo></products>
2         <products><productInfo><Item>Train</Item></productInfo></products>
3         <products></products>
```

I want to find all the rows that have `<products></products>`.

I tried this:

```
Select *
From products
Where productsxml.exist('/products') = 1
```

This is returning all the rows that have products tag and understandably so.

Is there a way to filter only those rows that have `<products></products>`?

Comment: `exist('/products[not(./*)]')=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease try the following solution.

It is checking that the root **products** element has no child elements.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ProductId int primary key, productsXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (ProductId, productsXML) VALUES
(1,'<products><productInfo><Item>Car</Item></productInfo></products>'),
(2,'<products><productInfo><Item>Train</Item></productInfo></products>'),
(3,'<products></products>');

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
Where productsxml.exist('/products[not(*)]')=1
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+--------------+
| ProductId | productsXML  |
+-----------+--------------+
|         3 | <products /> |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Alternatively `productsxml.exist('/products/*')=0` and the query plan looks better also https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c88ece4c15584a738b61990db6b7b0c The logic is subtly different: my version will also find XML which has no `<products>` node at all